# give a textblock a margin but only if there is content

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have 3 `textblocks` in a `stackpanel` in a `DataTemplate`.

the idea is that the format should be like "a b c" with spaces between the `textblocks` but it may happen that `textblocks` "a" and "b" might be empty, so i end up with something like this "  c" ( two spaces before `textblock` c). How can i ensure that i have a margin but only if there is content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `TextBlock`'s `Visibility` is set to `Collapsed`, the `Margin` will not be shown. So I guess you can use a `StringToVisibilityConverter` to set its `Visibility` to `Collapsed` if the `Text` is empty.

**Example**

First you need to create a converter like this.

```
public class StringToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return Visibility.Collapsed;

        if (value != null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()))
            return Visibility.Collapsed;

        return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you need to include this converter into your xaml.

```
<converters:StringToVisibilityConverter x:Key="StringToVisibilityConverter " />
```

Finally, use it inside your `TextBlock`.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Text="{Binding SomeText}"
         Visibility="{Binding SomeText, Converter={StaticResource StringToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

For more info regarding how to use a converter, please take a look at [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/15/so-what-s-a-silverlight-value-converter-anyway.aspx).

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: do you have a sample? i'm not that used to xaml so i'm a bit rusty

Answer (score 0):

Add a converter to the Margin and bind it to the `Text` property. Have the converter sent the margin to a uniform thickness of `0` if the text content is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Put the textblocks in a grid so that their locations are fixed.  Add a converter to the martin and bind it to the text property, and if the length of that text is zero, then set the margin to zero.